# Should I be awarded this bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

This question - [Node doesn't get removed from Firebase Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603121/node-doesnt-get-removed-from-firebase-database) - had a bounty that ended 2 hours ago. It says:

> Bounty will be immediately awarded to the answer that solves the
>   issue.

My answer was posted before the Community bounty was set *but* there was a bounty with the same reputation number by the now deleted OP (who marked my answer as correct) when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't 2 separate bounties here.  It is the same bounty that was originally set by the OP.  Here's roughly what probably transpired

1. OP sets a bounty with a message "Bounty will be immediately awarded to the answer that solves the issue."
2. You post your answer, OP marks it as accepted.
3. OP's account is deleted
4. Community assumes ownership of the bounty since the OP's account is deleted.
5. Bounty ends and we are 3 hours into the 24 hour grace period.

As for awarding your bounty, Community cannot manually award the bounty, it is a just a background process that handles stuff that can't be handled normally (like "owning" a bounty for a deleted user).

If you look at the [bounty info in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), there is a section called *How is a bounty awarded?*.  The most relevant for this case is:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

So in this case, since the OP did not award the bounty before the account was deleted, and Community can't award it, you'll have to wait for the grace period to end.  After that, per the rules quoted above, you should be awarded the full bounty since your answer was posted after the bounty was started, received at least 2 upvotes, and was accepted.  This assumes that your answer still meets that criteria when the grace period is over.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the grace period meant extra time for other answers to appear. So what is the reason for a grace period?

Comment: No, grace period is not extra time on the bounty.  The bounty is over.  It is a 24-hour period after the bounty ends to give the OP a chance to manually award the bounty.  That period still exists even if the OP is deleted.

Comment: It was the text "Bounty will be immediately awarded to the answer that solves the issue." which prompted this question. The OP cannot award the bounty as the account has been deleted so I assumed it would be awarded immediately. There was no mention of grace period in the bounty text initially.

Comment: The bounty text is a custom message written by the person who started the bounty.  In this case, the OP chose to write that message, but obviously didn't live up to his promise since he didn't award it immediately to you.  It could say "I will give $$$$ to the person that solves this problem", but it doesn't mean you will actually get cash from the bounty starters.